# Why i am getting wrong output?

Tags: c

Question :- Write a program to take five numbers by user and search a number is found or not.
My attempt :-

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main ()
{
    int a=2,b;char directory[5];int i;
    printf("enter a number you want to find");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&directory[i]);
    }
    if(a=directory[i]);
        printf("number is found");
    else
        printf("number not found");
    getch();
}
```

Description of the problem :-
I already gave `int a = 2` and after entering 5 values including 2 as one of the input but the output is coming out to be number not found.. suggest me the changes or the part which i need to work on.
Thank you!

**EDIT 1:-** after doing the changes proposed in the answer the code looks like this
but i am still not getting the correct output

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main ()
{
    int a=2,b;char directory[5];int i;
    printf("enter a number you want to find");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&directory[i]);
        if (a==directory[i])
        {
            printf("number is found");
        }
        else
            printf("number not found);
        } 
    }
    getch();
}
```

Comment: why initialize `a` to `2` if you're just going to scan in a number in it?

Comment: `=` is assignment, not comparison.

Comment: After the loop, `i` is 5. `directory[5]` is out of bounds.

Comment: @melpomene - welcome to C, an array-bounds-checking-free zone! :-)

Answer (score 2):

`%d` is expecting an `int` but `char directory[5]` is `char` values. This should be called as

```
int directory[5];
```

Also you are only looking at the value of `i` which at the end of the for loop previously would be 5 in the array in the line:

```
if(a=directory[i]);
```

You should instead have a for loop saying:

```
for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    if(a == directory[i])
    {
         printf("number is found");
    }
    else
    {
         printf("number not found");
    }
}
```

Two more things you should notice about my `if` are the `==` and the ending. Using a single `=` is an assignment which means a will now equal the value of `directory[i]` and check the boolean value if `a` is true (anything besides 0) or false (0). Writing it as `==` is what you want to check if they have the same value.

At the end of your `if` you have a semi colon. That makes the `if` pointless. The block will stop at the end of it.

**EDIT**
In your new edit you are still using a `char` array instead of `int`

```
char directory[5];
```

Should be:

```
int directory[5];
```

I assume it was just a copy paste issue but you are missing the opening { in your else. Either take out the closing } or add the other. Also assuming a copy paste issue for this one but you are missing the closing " in the line:

```
printf("number not found);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
char directory[5]
```

This needs to be of type `int` . As also you pass `char *` as argument to `%d` you programs exhibits undefined behaviour.

And this should be inside `for` loop -

```
if(a==directory[i]);  // out of loop i is out of bounds
   printf("number is found");
else
   printf("number not found");
```

Comment: After doing the following changes even after not including 2 as input in array the output says "Number Found".

Comment: @iCas As melpomene pointed out in comment it should be `if(a==directory[i])` .

Comment: Sorry,after the suggested corrections i am still not able to get the correct output will someone help me with the exact coding as i am having a bit of trouble in understanding how exactly and what i should edit... thanks!

Comment: @iCas Can you tell me excat input  ?

Comment: after running the code it asks for enter a number you want to find after entering input numbers 1 number not found 2 (no response) 3 number not found ... till 6 and code ends...

Comment: @iCas [Here is working code](https://ideone.com/AEm7G0). I made few changes (_for output to look good :)_)

Comment: what is meant by (flag==1) and flag=1?

Comment: @iCas It is a value used which changes to `1` if integer is found . So if it is found don;t loop further and print that you found the value. So insted of printing so many time just print once that you found the value.

Comment: if i am entering the input as 1 2 3 4 5 6 it says number not found despite the fact 2 is present but if i take all inputs to be 2 2 2 2 2 2 it shows number found ... how to fix this? @ameyCU

Comment: @iCas Did you change array size ?

Comment: @iCas If you want to search let say in array of `10` integers , then you need to make changes in declaration and loops accordingly .

Comment: i didnt change the size of the array why is it showing number found when all the entries are 2? and why not when just one input is  2 ? @ameyCU

Comment: @iCas There is no error in code. When you give input `1 2 3 4 5 6` , `a` becomes `1` because of `scanf` and array has `2 3 4 5 6` , so `1` is not in array .  So if you give input as `2 1 2 3 4 5` , then it would give `Number found`.

Comment: what should i change in code so i can assign values to the array and after then searching it?

Comment: @iCas You can move `scanf("%d",&a)` after taking input in array .

Comment: can you help me rearrage the code in link https://ideone.com/AEm7G0 so it takes the array values first and then search for the value .. @ameyCU

Answer (score 0):

```
 if(a=directory[i]);
```

If statements do NOT end with semi-colons!
You meant:

```
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    scanf("%d",&directory[i]);
    if(a == directory[i])
    {
        printf("number is found");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("number not found");
    }
}
getch();
```

Answer (score 0):

first mistake,you have to declare array as int

```
int directory[5]
```

second mistake is that in if condition you assigning value with "=" operator
you should use "==" operator

```
if(directory[i]==a)
```

"=" is assignment operator

if and else should be in the for loop

Answer (score 0):

In Your Code 
char directory[5] //You need to Declare it as an Integer to compare it with another integer
if(a=directory[i]); //You don't need to have semicolon here it does not make any sense
if(a=directory[i]); // You need to use == instead of = to compare
Finally, make them  within a loop. Happy Coding

Answer (score 0):

There appear to be some problems in the version of the program you posted; I've taken the liberty of correcting them below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main()
  {
  int a=2, b, i;
  int directory[5];
  int found=false;

  printf("Enter a number you want to find: ");
  scanf("%d",&a);

  printf("Enter the numbers you want to check\n");
  for(i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++)
    scanf("%d", &directory[i]);

  for(i = 0 ; i < 5 ; ++i)
    {
    if(a == directory[i])
      {
      found = true;
      break;
      }
    }

  if (found)
    printf("number is found\n");
  else
    printf("number not found\n");
  }
```

The most important thing is that the original code never looped through the array of entered values to see if any of them matched the target value. In addition, the "entered value" which was checked was not actually in the array (the index used was outside the range of the valid index values for the array), and the "comparison" was coded as an assignment ('=' was used instead of '=='), so what was being checked was whether the value in the byte after the end of the array was zero or non-zero. In this version of the program the array is defined as being of type `int` rather than `char`

Best of luck.

Comment: what is stdbool.h and can you explain int found = false < the use of it and then found = true?

Comment: [stdbool.h](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/stdbool.h.html)

Answer (score 0):

And you didnt initialize .It's logic fault

```
int directory[5]
```

Comment: how to fix it? where do i initialize it?